# Vue Group By Headings not Grouping

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vuejs2

Hey I want to group buttons under a heading. I have tried several methods with Vue, but none seem to work. I also don't get much errors. What I want to do is group buttons under a specific heading. I am using Laravel and Vue. There are 2 computed functions - I tried both, so I put both here as well.

Here is a part of my array in the Controller:

```
       $commands = [
    [
      'id' => 1,
      'signature' => 'sync:whatever',
      'arguments' =>'',
      'title' =>'Sync Whatever',
      'groupID' => 1,
      'groupName' => 'GroupOne'
    ],

    [
      'id' => 2,
      'signature' => 'send:whatever',
      'arguments' =>'users',
      'title' =>'Send Whatever',
      'groupID' => 1,
      'groupName' => 'GroupOne'
    ],

    [
      'id' => 3,
      'signature' => 'sync:something',
      'arguments' =>'',
      'title' =>'Sync Something',
      'groupID' => 2,
      'groupName' => 'GroupTwo'
    ],
    }
```

Here is my Vue component:

```
    <div v-for="(commands, groupName) in grouped">
    <h4>@{{ groupName }}</h4>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="btn-group" v-for="command in commands">

        <commands-component
                :entity-config="commandConfig(command.id, command.signature, command.arguments, command.title, command.groupID, command.groupName)">

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" v-bind:value="command.title">
        </commands-component>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My Computed:

```
     computed: {
      groupedCommands: function(){
          return this.commands.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.groupName] = r[a.groupName] || [];
            r[a.groupName].push(a);
            return r;
          }, Object.create(null));
        },

        grouped: function(){
          return _.mapValues(_.groupBy(this.commands, 'groupName'),
                      clist => clist.map(commands => _.omit(this.commands, 'groupName')));

        },

    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You have remove that input tag and put in button tag it will work

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">btn-1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">btn-2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">btn-3</button
</div>
```

Comment: The buttons are not a problem, it is the headings that wont group

Comment: can u share u output me

Comment: if I have my v-for like this:

        <div v-for="(commands, groupName) in groupedCommands">
        <h4>@{{ groupName }}</h4>
      </div>

Then the ouput shows 2 headings, but the buttons are not grouped under the headings. The headings are below each other at the top with 27 buttons below it, not grouped